# MS Excel for Mac - conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would greatly appreciate help in writing the code to do the following:

cell B7 is the sum of H7+I7+J7

when the sum in B7 is greater than 2 and less than 5 (i.e. either 3 or 4), I would like B7 to have a green fill and display the word "LOW)

I know how to do the colour fill part, but not how to get B7 to display text when the sum is a certain number - I have tried a couple of options:

1. I inserted a formula in B7 so that it = H7+I7+J7; and then created  a Conditional Format as follows: IF(AND(B7>2,B7<5),"LOW"
2. I deleted the SUM formula from B7 and created a Conditional Formula as follows: IF(AND(H7+I7+J7>2,H7+I7+J7<5),"LOW"

I also tried it without the "IF", but nothing works

HELP (please)

Answer (score 0):

First, both of your formulas are missing a close parethesis at the end and the FALSE statement.

Enter the following formula in B7,

=If(AND(sum(H7, I7, J7)>2, sum(H7, I7, J7)<5), "LOW", {enter false statement here})

As I think you have figured out, coloring a cell with conditional formatting and changing the value of a cell using If statements are usually two separate function.

Here is an example of nesting the IF statements:

=IF(AND(SUM(H7, I7, J7)>2, SUM(H7, I7, J7)<5), "LOW", IF(AND(SUM(H7, I7, J7)>4, SUM(H7, I7, J7)<8), "MEDIUM", IF(AND(.....{and so forth}

Look at these Microsoft Excel Course videos on advanced IF functions. [Microsoft Support Excel Advanced If Functions](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Advanced-IF-functions-17341cef-510d-4d60-a657-913f878fdacf)

Good Luck.

Comment: Dear Osol - thanks so much for your help - I haven't tried your solution yet, becuase I've been struggling with the FALSE statement

Comment: Dear Osol - thanks so much for your help - I haven't tried your solution yet, because I've been struggling with the FALSE statement - there's a second part to my challenge that I didn't mention - if the sum in B7 is another number, then I want it to say something else - i.e. if B7 is between 4 and 8 (i.e. 5 or 6), then "MEDIUM"; if B7 is between 6 and 9 (i.e. 7 or 8), then "HIGH"; if B7 is between 8 and 14 (9, 10, 11, 12 or 13), then "CRITICAL"  - would this be written as a single formula? or is each subformula written as a separate conditional format formula? if so, what is the FALSE statemnt

Comment: What you want to use is nested IF statements..you start another IF statement in place of {enter false statement here}, and continue to do so until all of your arguments are satisfied.

Comment: Hi, Osol - thanks for all your help - I followed your advice,a nd after a bit of trial and error, I got it to work - you're a genius - thanks again! here's the formula for anyone else that may be interested =IF(F7+G7+H7>=9,"CRITICAL",IF(F7+G7+H7>=7,"HIGH",IF(F7+G7+H7>=5,"MEDIUM",IF(F7+G7+H7>=3,"LOW", "INCOMPLETE"))))

Comment: Hi Frank, my pleasure helping.  If you could mark the answer I provided as accepted, that would help greatly.  Good Luck with your spreadsheet.